# popping from exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, email

I'm having issues getting a linux box to pop from exhcange 2007.

This all started while setting up osticket.  Once I had everything configured I get an invalid username/password them attempting to test the account settings.

I installed pop3test on ubuntu and found that the only way I can use it to get a clean login test is with the following command.

pop3test -a username -i mailservername
which outputs this:

```
S: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
C: CAPA
S: +OK
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: SASL NTLM GSSAPI PLAIN
S: USER
S: STLS
S: .
C: AUTH NTLM
S: +
C: TlRMTVNTUAABAAAABwIAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAA=
S: + TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAHgAeADgAAAAFAoECnKze+Uk9JdsAAAAAAAAAAOoA6gBWAAAABgBxFwAAAA9XAEgASQBUAEUATwBBAEsAUwBSAEUAUwBPAFIAVAACAB4AVwBIAEkAVABFAE8AQQBLAFMAUgBFAFMATwBSAFQAAQAaAFcATwAtAEUAWABIAC0AUwBWAFIALQAwADEABAAmAHcAaABpAHQAZQBvAGEAawBzAHIAZQBzAG8AcgB0AC4AYwBvAG0AAwBCAHcAbwAtAGUAeABoAC0AcwB2AHIALQAwADEALgB3AGgAaQB0AGUAbwBhAGsAcwByAGUAcwBvAHIAdAAuAGMAbwBtAAUAJgB3AGgAaQB0AGUAbwBhAGsAcwByAGUAcwBvAHIAdAAuAGMAbwBtAAcACABTHRrS2BnKAQAAAAA=
Please enter your password:
C: TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAYABgAQAAAAB4AHgBYAAAAFgAWAHYAAAAAAAAAjAAAAAAAAACMAAAABQIAACT4jYQ+x4K+9FukBf25KfQVtL0MAygiPFcASABJAFQARQBPAEEASwBTAFIARQBTAE8AUgBUAG0AYQBpAG4AdABlAG4AYQBuAGMAZQA=
S: +OK User successfully logged on.
Authenticated.
Security strength factor: 0
^CC: QUIT
Connection closed.
```

if i don't include the '-i' the command fails with:

```
S: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
C: CAPA
S: +OK
S: TOP
S: UIDL
S: SASL NTLM GSSAPI PLAIN
S: USER
S: STLS
S: .
C: AUTH NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAABwIAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAA=
S: -ERR Protocol error. Connection is closed. 10
Authentication failed. generic failure
Security strength factor: 0
Connection closed.
enter code here
```

fetchmailrc settings are:

```
set logfile ~/logs/fetchmail.log
set invisible
set no bouncemail
poll "mail"
protocol pop3
auth password
username "maintenance"
password "maintpass"
sslproto "ssl23"
fetchall
nokeep
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -m ~/.procmail.conf"
```

and the error it gives is:

```
fetchmail: 6.3.9-rc2 querying mail (protocol POP3) at Mon 10 Aug 2009 12:26:15 PM EDT: poll started
fetchmail: Trying to connect to 192.168.1.24/110...connected.
fetchmail: POP3< +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
fetchmail: POP3> USER maintenance
fetchmail: POP3< +OK
fetchmail: POP3> PASS *
fetchmail: POP3< -ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
fetchmail: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
fetchmail: Authorization failure on maintenance@server.domain.com
fetchmail: POP3> QUIT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 POP3 server signing off.
fetchmail: 6.3.9-rc2 querying mail (protocol POP3) at Mon 10 Aug 2009 12:26:15 PM EDT: poll completed
fetchmail: Query status=3 (AUTHFAIL)
fetchmail: normal termination, status 3
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a permanent fix for this issue here: [LINK](http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?p=9456)

It lets you disable TLS in the PHP mail client that osticket uses.

Answer (score 1):

In your pop3test command, you are using NTLM authentication; your Fetchmail log suggests it is doing PLAIN.  If your server is only set up to respond to NTLM correctly, you may need to ensure that NTLM is compiled into your Fetchmail binary and enable it in the fetchmailrc file.

Comment: If I enable the ntlm mode in the fetchmail config I still get an unknown user or bad password message, the exchange log also shows that NTLM was used for the attempt and that it failed.

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another this actually was a credentials issue.  I had an account named Maintenance with username/alias maintenance and email address maintenance@domain.com.  I created a new user account calle maint, with username/alias maint and email of maint@domain.com

for some reason maint works in all cases where the maintenance account does not,  I've still not tracked down the exact issue but it is up and running...